# Can i incorporate CSS directly in a mustache file?

Tags: css, plugins, moodle

Can I can incorporate CSS such as using the " in a mustache file for a Moodle plugin?

I am new to plugin and I'm still learning, any feedback is welcome.

[image: Simple Table in Mustache file for Moodle Plugin.]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<style>` tag? Or a `<link>` referencing your CSS file?

Comment: @juzraai yes, I already have a separate file for the style but nothing happens. But i will type the link, thanks!

Comment: Make your CSS filename to styles.css and the file should be in your plugin's root folder. Then Moodle will include your styles automatically.  Please do purge caches. Thanks